# How to fix "Django celery is getting task and start processing but not completing the full job"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, django-celery

I am working with MaskRCNN popular instance segementation problem using tensorflow and keras. I am also using django restframework to process. While celery recieve the task it starts processing and stuck in the middle. Like I am processing two images and getting inference out of them. But after processing the first image celery stucks.

I am using Amazon ec2 - g3s.xlarge with ubuntu deep learning AMI, django rest framework, celery, tensorflow and keras

Big project thats why can't show the code

getting inference from two image processing but getting stuck in the middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the fix with this command -

```
celery -A prodapi worker -l info --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat -Ofair --pool=solo
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Overlord